# Is Tuesday a better day for Press Releases and similar information?

Tags: psychology, advertising, work, management

I remember reading an article about Tuesday being the best day to get maximum reach for your message.  I think this study came from Harvard.  The content of the message could be PR or some other communication.

Is there evidence for this?

Comment: It should be easy to find the press release for this research. You can narrow it down to search for ones released on a Tuesday... :-)

Comment: -1 for no evidence of "research". You say, "I remember reading..." ... and I say, phooey! Can't you do any better than that?

Comment: It's certainly a great day for monkeys

Comment: @ChrisW - I did google, and best I could find was a Harvard publication called Tuesday Mag.  The "about" section didn't expose what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what sort of press release you are talking about. You may like to focus the question more.

For example, in a recent document, three accountancy researchers claim:

> While there is considerable research on the timing of
> interim and annual financial reports, there is a scarcity of research on the timing of nonperiodic disclosures.

Reference: 
Balatbat, Maria C. A., Gallery, Gerry Thomas and Jackson, Andrew B., [The Strategic Timing of Management Earnings Forecasts](http://ssrn.com/abstract=1827188) (February 15, 2011)

They go on to provide evidence that organisations do deliberately delay financial disclosures to hit certain days of the week.

I believe this was for a conference proceeding, and not peer-reviewed, but was based on a PhD thesis.